# issue with tabBarIcon in react navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I want to set an icon for tab navigation but it returns an error

This is my code:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{tabBarIcon:'home'}} />
```

This is the error i get:

[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You must set **showIcon** property to **true** in **tabBarOptions** like this:

```
  <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{ showIcon: true }}>
```

and then you can set the icon for your screen like this:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ tabBarIcon:(tabInfo) => (<MaterialIcons name="home" size={18} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />)}}/>
```

full code example:

```
 import React from "react";
    import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
    import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
    import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

    const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

    const MyTabs = (props) => {
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions={{ showIcon: true, showLabel: false }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => (
                <MaterialIcons name="home" size={18} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    };

    export default MyTabs;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: You are the best

Answer (score 2):

Just as one of the solutions given above, we can create a TabBarIcon component and gave it the props of name and focused.

```
import React from "react"
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons"

export default function TabBarIcon({ name, focused }) {
  return (
    <Ionicons
      name={name}
      size={25}
      color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"}
      style={{ marginBottom: -10 }}
    />
  )
}
```

Then import it in the App.js file and on the tabBarIcon option, return the TabBarIcon component

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar"
import React from "react"
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"

import HomeScreen from "./app/screens/HomeScreen"
import TabBarIcon from "./app/components/TabBarIcon"

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          showIcon: true,
          activeTintColor: "tomato",
          inactiveTintColor: "gray",
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 12,
            padding: 10,
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          initialRouteName="Home"
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
              <TabBarIcon
                focused={focused}
                name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? `ios-home` : "md-home"}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the real way (TabBarIcon file)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function TabBarIcon(props) {
    return (
        <Ionicons
            name={props.name}
            size={26}
            color={props.focused ? 'red' : 'black'}
            style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
        />
    );
}
```

and you need to select the right icon (ios and md)(Part of router.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import TabBarIcon from "./components/TabBarIcon";
import Home from './components/Home';
import Register from './components/Register'

// Home page
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: Home,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? `ios-home`
                    : 'md-home'
            }
        />
    ),
};

HomeStack.path = '';
```

Comment: Buddy i mentioned that i am looking for solution for version 5 but you wrote your codes in version 4

Comment: Version 5 : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#customizing-the-appearance

Comment: Almost the same way check this link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I tried what was described above in the answers I was still getting the label shown in the tab bar. It only disappeared when I added `labeled={false}` as a prop to the Navigator.

Example

```
<Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    labeled={false}
    sceneAnimationEnabled={false}
  >
etc
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

<Tab.Screen 
    name="Home" 
    component={Home} 
    options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 6 }}> // Your Style Here
                <Icon name={'md-add-circle'} color={color} />
            </Text>
        )
    }} 
/>
```

I hope you like it!!!